# Gmail intercepts event invites sent to iCloud account

Tags: gmail, icloud, icalendar

I use my Gmail address as my primary iCloud email address. When someone sends me an event invite to this email address, Gmail intercepts it and adds it to my Gmail calendar (which I don't use) instead of letting Apple Calendar handling it.

Do you know how I can tell Gmail to leave the event invites to iCloud?

Answer (score -1):

First google result has instructions 
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

You could  also just not use, untick the calendar in your calendar apps.